# Slavery to the grossest superstition

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence especially the bold part

> History, as well as daily experience, furnishes instances of men endowed with the strongest capacity for business and affairs, who have all their lives  **crouched under slavery to the grossest superstition**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words "crouched under slavery" are being used as a metaphor for "control by". The writer is saying that otherwise highly competent people were nonetheless subject to superstition, that is believed the superstition and to some extent regulated their lives by it.  It doesn't say what kind of superstition or how it affected the people.  "grossest" here means that the superstition was a particularly blatant or obvious one.